# Multiple text inputs to neural network

Tags: neural-networks, text-classification

How do I best input multiple text fields in a neural network for classification?  For example, each data point has a title and an abstract:

```
title:    Neural Networks for Pattern Recognition
abstract: This book provides the first comprehensive treatment of feed-forward neural networks from the perspective of statistical pattern recognition. [...]
```

When looking at other people's code these 2 fields a frequently concatenated, with or without boundary symbols, before being fed to a neural network.  Is there a better to do it?